# Pasting Copied Cells without overwriting previous data

Tags: vba, excel

I am using file dialog to copy data from various excel files and paste them on a single worksheet. The second file however overwrites the data from the first file. The 1st data was pasted on range A2:E2710 on the destination workbook. If the 2nd set of data range is A2:A118, it will overwrite A2:A118 on the destination workbook. How do I get it to paste and not overwrite the previously pasted data?  I've tried Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown but that does not paste the data. Please help.

```
Sub FASB_Select()
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Set ExcelSheet = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
 'Declare a variable to contain the path
    'of each selected item. Even though the path is a String,
    'the variable must be a Variant because For Each...Next
    'routines only work with Variants and Objects.
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
    With fd
    'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
    'The user pressed the action button.
    If .Show = -1 Then

        Sheets("Data").Select

        'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

            'vrtSelectedItem is a String that contains the path of each selected item.
            'You can use any file I/O functions that you want to work with this path.
            'This example simply displays the path in a message box.
            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (vrtSelectedItem)
            'Clear CutCopyMode
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            'Wait some time
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' wait 3 seconds
            DoEvents

            'IN Excel :
            'SELECT ALL
             Range("A2").Select
             Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
             Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
             Selection.Copy
            'EXIT (Close & Exit)
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' wait 3 seconds
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

            'Wait some time
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' wait 3 seconds
             Range("A2").Select
            'Paste

             ActiveSheet.Paste

            Next vrtSelectedItem  'Loop for each file selected in the file dialog box

    'Exit if the user pressed Cancel
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

'Set the object variable to Nothing
Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Where *should* each section be pasted?

Answer (score 0):

In the worksheet named "Data" that's in the wb that contains the macro. I want the succeeding copied data to automatically paste in the cell below the last active cell.